# How to conditionally run an action on Azure Logic Apps using inLineCode

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic apps flow where I need to call other logic apps flows.
I have a variable which determines which logic apps flow to call. I would prefer not to use the switch statement because in the future I could have hundreds of different cases.

I would prefer to create inline javascript code with all of the conditions and then if I possibly configure the logic apps process variables to select the Logic apps flow that I picked in javascript.
I would also prefer to use this over making an HTTP request on javascript because I would assume the calling the logic app action is better than an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables to select Logic App workflows isn't possible, unfortunately, so you do need to use HTTP actions instead as they don't have this limitation.